# create mysql table using ansible in RDS

Tags: mysql, ansible, rds

Is there any way to use ansible to create MySQL table in RDS?
According to mysql_db module page, "target" should specify the
location of the file on "remote" host. In case of RDS, I don't
think I can put file on RDS instance.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reference the file from the `localhost`

```
- hosts: localhost
  sudo: no
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Run SQL commands against DB to create table
      mysql_db:
        login_host: "{{ DB_HOST }}"
        login_password: "{{ DB_PASSWORD }}"
        login_user: "{{ DB_USER }}"
        login_port: "{{ DB_PORT }}"
        name: "{{ DB_NAME }}"
        state: import
        target: "{{ path_to_my_sql_files_on_ansible_machine }}/create.sql"
```

Comment: thanks, i just realized it didn't work because i forgot to put "state"

Comment: What is "ansible_machine"? The node or the host?